# Scatterchart values disappear when dragging

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I have multiple scattercharts in a ListView. Every chart contains 365 xvalues (every day of the year). The yvalues vary from 1 to 5. The height of the charts is 150dp. 
I center my chart to the current day of the year (xIndex).

```
holder.chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
holder.chart.setDragEnabled(true);
holder.chart.setScaleEnabled(false);
holder.chart.setScaleMinima(3f, 1f);
holder.chart.centerViewPort(xIndex, 3);
```

When i drag to the left on the chart, the scatters just disappear.
Eg: I see about 10 scatters with yValue=1. When I drag to he left, as soon as the most right scatter with yValue=1 gets out of the chartrange, all other scatters with the same yValue also disappear.
How can I prevent this?

First pic, you see 3 scatter charts.

[image]

After swiping on the middle chart you see aug 29 appearing, but the green, blue and grey scatters disappear:

[image]

Some additional info:
The listView is inside a fragment. The fragment is inside a ViewPager. The ViewPager is inside a tab of a FragmentTabhost

The code for creating the charts and add them to the listview:

```
for(int j = 0 ; j < rpya.size(); j++)
    {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.clear();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, rpya.get(j).year);
        cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        Calendar caltarget = Calendar.getInstance();
        caltarget.clear();
        caltarget.set(Calendar.YEAR, rpya.get(j).year + 1);
        caltarget.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        caltarget.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        ArrayList<String> newxVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (cal.before(caltarget)){
            newxVals.add(new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.day_month)).format(cal.getTime()).toString());
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
        }
        list.add(new ScatterChartItem(String.valueOf(rpya.get(j).year), generateScatterData(rpya.get(j).ratings, newxVals), getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

    }

    ChartDataAdapter cda = new ChartDataAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list);
    lv.setAdapter(cda);
```

The code for adding the data, the adapter and the charttype:

```
protected ScatterData generateScatterData(ArrayList<SubjectNote> sn, ArrayList<String> xVals) {


    ScatterChart.ScatterShape[] shapes = ScatterChart.getAllPossibleShapes();
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals3 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals5 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals7 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Entry> yVals9 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
    ArrayList<Integer> pos1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> pos3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> pos5 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> pos7 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> pos9 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int len = xVals.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < sn.size(); i++) {
        int pos = 0;
        //determine position by xVals
        pos = xVals.indexOf(new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.day_month)).format(sn.get(i).date).toString());

        Calendar cItem = Calendar.getInstance();
        cItem.setTime(sn.get(i).date);
        int year = sn.get(i).ranking;
        switch (sn.get(i).ranking){

            case 1:
                if(pos1.indexOf(pos) < 0) {
                    yVals1.add(new Entry(year, pos));
                    pos1.add(pos);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(pos3.indexOf(pos) < 0) {
                    yVals3.add(new Entry(year, pos));
                    pos3.add(pos);
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if(pos5.indexOf(pos) < 0) {
                    yVals5.add(new Entry(year, pos));
                    pos5.add(pos);
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                if(pos7.indexOf(pos) < 0) {
                     yVals7.add(new Entry(year, pos));
                    pos7.add(pos);
                }
                break;
            case 9:
                if(pos9.indexOf(pos) < 0) {
                    yVals9.add(new Entry(year, pos));
                    pos9.add(pos);
                }
                break;
        }

    }
    // create a dataset and give it a type
    ScatterDataSet set1 = new ScatterDataSet(yVals1, "--");
    set1.setScatterShape(ScatterChart.ScatterShape.CIRCLE);
    set1.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color1inner));
    ScatterDataSet set3 = new ScatterDataSet(yVals3, "-");
    set3.setScatterShape(ScatterChart.ScatterShape.CIRCLE);
    set3.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color3inner));
    ScatterDataSet set5 = new ScatterDataSet(yVals5, "0");
    set5.setScatterShape(ScatterChart.ScatterShape.CIRCLE);
    set5.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color5inner));
    ScatterDataSet set7 = new ScatterDataSet(yVals7, "+");
    set7.setScatterShape(ScatterChart.ScatterShape.CIRCLE);
    set7.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color7inner));
    ScatterDataSet set9 = new ScatterDataSet(yVals9, "++");
    set9.setScatterShape(ScatterChart.ScatterShape.CIRCLE);
    set9.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color9inner));

    set1.setScatterShapeSize(10f);
    set3.setScatterShapeSize(10f);
    set5.setScatterShapeSize(10f);
    set7.setScatterShapeSize(10f);
    set9.setScatterShapeSize(10f);

    ArrayList<ScatterDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<ScatterDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1); // add the datasets
    dataSets.add(set3);
    dataSets.add(set5);
    dataSets.add(set7);
    dataSets.add(set9);

    // create a data object with the datasets
    ScatterData d = new ScatterData(xVals, dataSets);

    return d;
}

private class ChartDataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChartItem> {

    public ChartDataAdapter(Context context, List<ChartItem> objects) {
        super(context, 0, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getItem(position).getView(position, convertView, getContext());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        // return the views type
        return getItem(position).getItemType();
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 4; // we have 4 different item-types
    }
}
```

The chartitem:

```
public abstract class ChartItem {

protected static final int TYPE_BARCHART = 0;
protected static final int TYPE_LINECHART = 1;
protected static final int TYPE_PIECHART = 2;
protected static final int TYPE_SCATTERCHART = 3;
protected ChartData mChartData;
protected String mDescription;
protected Context mContext;

public ChartItem(String description, ChartData cd, Context c){
    this.mChartData = cd;
    this.mDescription = description;
    this.mContext = c;
}

public abstract int getItemType();

public abstract View getView(int position, View convertView, Context c);
```

}

The scatterchart itself:

```
public class ScatterChartItem extends ChartItem {

public ScatterChartItem(String Description, ChartData cd, Context c) {
    super(Description, cd, c);


}

@Override
public int getItemType() {
    return TYPE_SCATTERCHART;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, Context c) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int xIndex = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item_scatterchart, null);
        holder.chart = (ScatterChart) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chart);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //Typeface mTf = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),"OpenSans-Light.ttf");
    final ViewHolder mHolder = holder;
    // apply styling
    //holder.chart.setValueTypeface(mTf);
    holder.chart.setDescription(mDescription);
    holder.chart.setDrawVerticalGrid(false);
    holder.chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    holder.chart.setDrawYValues(false);
    holder.chart.setHighlightIndicatorEnabled(false);
    holder.chart.setDrawLegend(false);
    holder.chart.setDrawYLabels(true);
    holder.chart.setDrawHorizontalGrid(false);
    holder.chart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(5);
    holder.chart.setPinchZoom(true);

    holder.chart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    holder.chart.setDragEnabled(true);
    holder.chart.setScaleEnabled(true);
    holder.chart.setScaleMinima(3f, 1f);
    holder.chart.centerViewPort(xIndex, 3);

    holder.chart.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    XLabels xl = holder.chart.getXLabels();
    xl.setCenterXLabelText(false);
    xl.setPosition(XLabels.XLabelPosition.BOTTOM);
    //xl.setTypeface(mTf);

    YLabels yl = holder.chart.getYLabels();
    yl.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    //yl.setTypeface(mTf);
    yl.setLabelCount(0);

    // set data
    holder.chart.setData((ScatterData) mChartData);

    // do not forget to refresh the chart
    //holder.chart.invalidate();
    holder.chart.animateY(700);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    ScatterChart chart;
}
```

}

Comment: I just tested your issue and unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue. Could you show a screenshot of what is happening?

Comment: Thank you. I have just uploaded a new version (1.7.4) of the library. The .jar file is available in the release section. Please try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, still the same result. Scatters disappear when swiping.

Comment: Allright. Could you show me the whole code you use for the chart and listview? (also adapter). Maybe I can find the issue there.

Comment: Added the code. Hope you find something.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, by reading the code I can see the following that could cause your problems. The first one has to do with the chart-library, the others are issues concerning your `ListView` implementation.

- Call `setScaleMinima(...)` and `centerViewPort(...)` after calling `setData(...)`.
- Since you are only using one type of list-item (the item with `ScatterChart` in it) it the method `getItemType()` is not necessary.
- If you only have one item-type, do not override the `getItemViewType(...)` method and `getViewTypeCount(...)` method in the adapter. Simply delete those. These methods should only be overridden if you want to support different item-types in your `ListView`.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Ok. IF you want to, you can send me (email) your whole project and i will try to make it work. (go to my github page: https://github.com/PhilJay  the email is there).

Comment: Send you an email, got it?

Comment: Yes, I got it. I will have a look at it tomorrow and then give you feedback.

Comment: I located the problem Philipp. It is not in your library. Just have to figure out a solution. If you want, I will let you know what the problem was.